# Difficulty in accessing sub directories files because of htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, web

This is my `.htaccess` code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php?rquest=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php [QSA,NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php [QSA,NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images/   

</IfModule>
```

My directory structure:

[image: Directory structure]

My problem is that I can access my api.php by calling  `/users` or `/getData` etc. But if I go for `images/someImage.jpg` then it not allowing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple rewrite rule

```
RewriteBase /your web directory
```

`RewriteEngine On`

`RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ api.php?rquest=$1`

`RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ api.php?rquest=$1`

the following is the break down of the code

`RewriteBase / #enter your directory root here`

`RewriteEngine On`

the following rewrite rule will redirect for example www.example.com/home to example.com/api.php?rquest=$1

`RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ api.php?rquest=$1`

and the following will redirect for example www.example/home/ to example.com/api.php?rquest=$1. notice the / after /home

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ api.php?rquest=$1
```

the above lines of code excludes the rule to redirect www.example.com/images/someimages.jpg to www.example.com/

So this will work for now.

Comment: RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ api.php?rquest=$1 i also tried this one but still its nit allowing subdirecties file

Comment: Maybe I didnt get the question in the first place. Can you explain more, I can help

Comment: Suppose I hit the URl as www.mydomain.com/login then it will call login method  api.php, if www.mydomain.com/users it will cal users method in api.php for that we did "RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ api.php?rquest=$1" but no because of this rule i am not abel to access www.mydomain.com/images/some.jpg